# Can I use UNPAIRED post-hoc analysis for PAIRED omnibus testing?

Tags: post-hoc, paired-data, kruskal-wallis-test

If I have a omnibus statistical test with unpaired assumption (e.g.Kruskall-Wallis), could I ever use the opposite (paired) post-hoc analysis? (e.g. Wilcoxon signed-rank for post-hoc analysis of Kruskall-Wallis), or rather I should stick with the same paired/unpaired logic?

Comment: If the data is unpaired, why would you use a paired test?

Comment: I've seen several highly-cited papers doing that. That's the reason for my question.

Comment: You should stick with the same paired/unpaired logic. I don't know why the people in these papers that you mention did not follow this logic, but it could be a case of p-hacking. You may want to ask a new question with some specific examples with sources, so that we may better assess the situation.

Comment: Thanks, I will follow your advice and post a new question with the references.

Comment: @user2974951 New question here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/418626/why-several-studies-change-logical-paired-unpaired-assumption-from-omnibus-to-po