# Why several studies change logical paired/unpaired assumption from omnibus to post-hoc?

Tags: statistical-significance, post-hoc, paired-data, wilcoxon-signed-rank, kruskal-wallis-test

There are several studies of highly-referenced researchers where a paired post-hoc test (e.g. Wilcoxon signed-rank) follows the omnibus unpaired test (e.g. Kruskal-Wallis):

From Huang et. al ["THE BACH DOODLE: APPROACHABLE MUSIC COMPOSITION WITH
MACHINE LEARNING AT SCALE"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.06637)

> A Kruskal-Wallis H test for
>   both the number of P5s and P8s showed that there is at
>   least one statistically significant difference between the
>   four categories... Further, Mann-Whitney
>   rank tests between the categories showed significant differences,
>   ...

From Roberts et al. ["A Hierarchical Latent Vector Model for Learning Long-Term Structure in Music"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.05428)

> ... a Kruskal-Wallis H test of the ratings showed that there was a statistically significant difference between the models... A post-hoc analysis using the Wilcoxon signed- rank test with Bonferroni correction showed that participants rated samples...

A possible clue (which is not enough for me) arises from the last reference: Huang et al's ["Music Transformer: generating music with long-term structure"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.04281), where after a Kruskal-Wallis test, there are 2 post-hoc analysis, one with (paired) Wilcoxon signed-rank and another with (unpaired) Mann-Whitney U test.

> A Kruskal-Wallis H test of the ratings showed that there was a statistically significant difference between the models... Table 5 show a post-hoc analysis on the comparisons within each pair, using the Wilcoxon signed-rank test for matched samples. Table 6 shows a post-hoc analysis of how well each model performed when compared to all pairs, and compares each model’s aggregate against each other, using the Mann–Whitney U test for independent samples.